# IE 8 specific issue with angularjs directives

Tags: internet-explorer-8, angularjs

This is a boiled-down repro of a problem I'm having in a much larger app. I can't seem to find a solution for it. If you run this in IE8, the `ui-popup` directive doesn't work, and the script debugger console has the error message `"TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or methodundefined"`.

I tried to strip away as many directives, controllers, and as much code as possible.

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xf2BX/)

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xf2BX/. I notice a lot of your styles are not IE compatible (it doesn't load right in ie9 for me)

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle. IE compatibility is more of a "does it work?" question for me, not a "does it look its best?" thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you downgrade angularjs to 1.0.3 it works in ie8.

**Edit**
Angular 1.0.5 also works.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose this means it's a regression?